# ConfigurationSection with multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net solution i have a couple of class library-projects that act as modules of the site.
In main project I have SiteConfigurationSection class that derives from ConfigurationSection.

I want  all projects to be able to access and use this SiteConfigurationSection.
But class library projects can't access it because they obviously don't have a reference to the website itself.

Should create a special library-project for SiteConfigurationSection of maybe it's better to create a mini SiteConfigurationSection class in every project and encapsulate only the needed values?

Answer (score 4):

Creating a common assembly for things like shared configuration types, shared interfaces, domain objects etc. is the appropriate action.

Just create a separate class library and reference it in each project that needs to read the configuration.